# Wordpress Custom Widget With Image chooser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am hoping that someone might have a solution to my problem. Here's the issue.

I am building a widget in WordPress that let's an admin choose an image from the media chooser, when an image is chosen the change doesn't update in the web page preview and the "save & publish" button remains disabled.

Other fields work just fine, I believe it's something to do with javascript not triggering the change unlike manually typing in a text input box.

Choosing an image does change the value of the input field with the correct image url but the changes aren't being recognised thus the save button remains disabled in the customizer.

Bootstrap 4.
WordPress 4.7.1

here's my code.

```js
(function($) {

 $(document).ready( 
  function() {
   console.log("loaded");

   var customUploader = wp.media({
    title: "Select an Image",
    library: { type: "image" },
    button: {
     text: 'Use this Image'
    },
    multiple: false,
   });

   var _this = null;

   //customUploader.open();
   $(document).on('click', '#image-upload-button', function(){
    _this = $(this);
    if(customUploader)
     customUploader.open();
   });

   customUploader.on('select', function(){
    var attachment = customUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

    _this.siblings('img').attr('src', attachment.url);
    _this.siblings('[id*=-img]').val(attachment.url);
    return true;
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
/*
 Plugin Name: Custom Bootstrap Card
 Plugin URI:
 Description: Test
 Version: 1.0
 Author: Alen Kalac
 License: none

*/
class custom_bs4_card extends WP_Widget {
 function __construct() {
  parent::__construct('ke-menu-stuff', $name = __('Custom Card'));
 }

 function widget( $args, $instance ) {

  var_dump($instance);
  $title = $instance['title'];
  $img = $instance['img'];

  echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
   <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<?php  echo $img; ?>"  alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
     <?php 
      if ( $title )
       echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
     ?>
     <p class="card-text">
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
     </p>
     <div class="card-cta">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
 <?php 
 }

 function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
  $instance = $old_instance;
  $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
  $instance['img'] = $new_instance['img'];
  $instance['url'] = $new_instance['url'];
  return $instance;
 }

 function form( $instance ) {

  $title =  ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'Promo Title', 'ke_template' );
  $url =   ! empty( $instance['url'] ) ? $instance['url'] : esc_html__( '#', 'ke_template' );
  $img =   ! empty( $instance['img'] ) ? $instance['img'] : esc_html__( '', 'ke_template' );
 ?>
  <p>
   <label 
    for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?>
   </label> 
   <input 
    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" 
    name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" 
    type="text" 
    value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>"
   >
  </p>

  <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $img ); ?>"  id="img-src">

  <input 
   type="text" 
   id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'img' ) ); ?>" 
   name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'img' ) ); ?>"  
   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $img ); ?>"
  >

  <input type="button" id="image-upload-button" value="Upload Image">

  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'url' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'URL:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
   <input class="btn btn-primary" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'url' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'url' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $url ); ?>">
  </p>


  <?php

 }
}

function ke_init() {
 register_widget('custom_bs4_card');
 
}

function enqueue_media_uploader()
{
 wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-upload-box', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "upload-box.js", array('jquery'), '0.1', false);
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ke_init');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', "enqueue_media_uploader");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem of: "Choosing an image does change the value of the input field"
The JQuery Selector `[id*=-img]` miss the "".
It should be `[id*="-img"]`